# Nested libraries in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, dlna

In Windows 11, I notice that when viewing the Libraries in Explorer, each top-level entry has a subfolder with the same name:

- > Libraries > Documents > Documents
- > Libraries > Music > Music
- > Libraries > Pictures > Pictures
- > Libraries > Videos > Videos

This extra layer of folders is also visible when I access this PC for media streaming to my Roku.

Is this the normal behavior?  If not how do I fix it?

[image: Explorer screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. I see the same thing on my Windows 11 computer. I did not set the libraries up that way myself; that is how they are by default.

The top-level entries (with the icons that have a blue line at the bottom) are the library names. The entries below them are the default folders included in the libraries - these folders just happen to have the same name as the libraries.

If you open the Properties window of one of the libraries, you'll see it listed as a Library, with buttons for adding and removing folders to the library.

If you open the Properties window of the same-named folder under the library, you'll see it listed as a System Folder. It will show the folder location, which by default is under C:\Users\[user name].

In other words, the Music library contains a "Music" folder whose path is like C:\Users\[user name]\Music. The Pictures library contains a "Pictures" folder whose path is like C:\Users\[user name]\Pictures. Etc.

If you wish, you can add other folders to the libraries. And if you don't want to use the default folders, you can remove them.

For information on changing the libraries' default save locations, see:

https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-default-save-locations-for-libraries-in-windows-11.5974/

Answer (score 1):

The extra Libraries are how you set it up. It is not default behavior.

To remove, make sure REAL documents are moved out to regular Documents.

Once libraries are empty, remove them.

That should do it.

You can always set up one Library if you need it.

I do not use Libraries because they serve no purpose in further organizing my well-organized documents.